# find out where all of my folders are

Tags: bash, unix

I have a lot of folders (as seen from `find ./ -type d | wc -l`)

I would like to find out where all of the large numbers of folders are.

Ideally, I would like the output of filelight but where each folder counts as 1 an everything else counts as 0.

I wonder if this is similar to

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117093/find-where-inodes-are-being-used

but that is for files only as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the tree command in linux:

```
tree
```

or

```
tree -p
```

shows file **permissions**

or

```
tree -s
```

shows file **size**

You can find the complete list here: [link](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm)

There are other properties. check this command.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure which output you exactly wish, given following directory structure:

```
$ find ./ -type d
./
./dir1
./dir1/dir_lvl2
./dir1/dir_lvl2/dir_lvl3
./dir1/dir_lvl2/dir2_lvl3
./dir2
./dir3
./dir3/dir_lvl2
```

You could simply get this:

```
$ find ./ -type d  | nawk -F "/" '{print $2}' |  uniq -c | sort -r
   4 dir1
   2 dir3
   1 dir2
   1
```

Answer (score 0):

KDirStat / QDirStat can give you that information: Both have a separate column for "number of directories" in the tree. You can even sort by that column and then open tree branches until you found what you have been looking for.

--
HuHa (KDirStat / QDirStat author)